# How to configure two processes in a heroku dyno to communicate with each other

Tags: http, heroku, networking

I'm trying to establish communication between 2 processes running in a single heroku dyno, which according to this documentation should be possible:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#networking

```
Individual processes within a dyno can bind to any address or port they want and communicate among them using e.g. standard TCP
```

I'm attempting to use http and the code works fine on my development machine. But when I try to execute the same thing on heroku, the source process can't connect to the target process. One process is running using nodejs and the other process is running using python.

Here's the contents of the Procfile:

```
web: npm run start
worker: python3 -m scripts.app
```

Here's part of the axios error message from the originating node process:

```
020-11-17T18:30:22.385020+00:00 app[web.1]: Inside nltk error block
2020-11-17T18:30:22.387506+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5010
2020-11-17T18:30:22.387507+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
2020-11-17T18:30:22.387508+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2020-11-17T18:30:22.387508+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2020-11-17T18:30:22.387509+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
2020-11-17T18:30:22.387509+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
2020-11-17T18:30:22.387509+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 5010,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) defines the process types. They will be run *in separate containers*.

If you want to run multiple processes in one dyno, your `Procfile` should have only one entry and one processes that will have your services are children.

There are [several methods and buildpacks to achieve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836979/can-the-same-dyno-run-multiple-processes/44509739#44509739).